# how dynamic created texbox value visible?(lost in post back)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

The `lnkcat` is the linkbutton for Category  and `lnksubcat` is the link button for Sub-category:

My problem is when i click on `lnk_cat` the corresponding label and textbox will be displayed... but i click on next lnk subcat will be removed....I want to hold these textboxes corresponding labels on the placeholder till i click on submit:

```
protected void lnkCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{    
    //Panel2.Visible = false;
    //Panel1.Visible = true;
    Label lblCat = new Label();
    lblCat.Text = "Enter new Category: ";
    PHcat.Controls.Add(lblCat);

    txtCat = new TextBox();
    _Cat = txtCat.Text;
    PhtxtCat.Controls.Add(txtCat);
    Session["Dynalbl"] = lblCat;
    Session["Dynatxt"] = txtCat;
}

protected void lnkSubCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Panel1.Visible = true;
    //Panel2.Visible = true;

    Label lblSubcat = new Label();
    lblSubcat.Text =  "Enter new Sub-Category: ";
    PHsubCat.Controls.Add(lblSubcat);

    txtSubCat = new TextBox();
    _SubCat = txtSubCat.Text;
    PhtxtSubCat.Controls.Add(txtSubCat);
}
```

Can anyone suggest to solve this issue? please!!

Thank you...

Comment: Enable ViewState, FTW!

Comment: You'll have to keep track of which controls are supposed to shown and which aren't and then readd them on every postback. Also, you should assign an ID to every control since you will lose the viewstate for it if it doesn't have the same ID. I think this is what you want, but it's kind of hard to tell.

Comment: i already put Enable ViewState = true;

Comment: ViewState only keeps track of what was on the page in the original GET request, plus any new values, that's why you should readd the controls with the same ID when you're dealing with dynamic control creation.

Comment: Hi the general rule of the thumb in this case is to create the dynamic control as early as possible like for e.g. in the page_init. You can use the ViewState object or any other hidden field to determine if such a control need to be created or not...

Comment: try adding onclick="return false;" to the buttons; maybe they are getting reset on a postback.

Comment: did you check the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this?

```
Label lblCat;
    Label lblSubcat;
    TextBox txtCat, txtSubCat;
    protected void lnkCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Panel2.Visible = false;
        //Panel1.Visible = true;
        Label lblCat = new Label();
        lblCat.Text = "Enter new Category: ";
        PHcat.Controls.Add(lblCat);

        txtCat = new TextBox();
        _Cat = txtCat.Text;
        PhtxtCat.Controls.Add(txtCat);
        Session["Dynalbl"] = lblCat;
        Session["Dynatxt"] = txtCat;
    }

    protected void lnkSubCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Panel1.Visible = true;
        //Panel2.Visible = true;
        lblCat = (Label)Session["Dynalbl"];
        txtCat = (TextBox)Session["Dynatax"];
        PHsubCat.Controls.Add(lblCat);
        PHsubCat.Controls.Add(txtCat);

        Label lblSubcat = new Label();
        lblSubcat.Text = "Enter new Sub-Category: ";
        PHsubCat.Controls.Add(lblSubcat);

        txtSubCat = new TextBox();
        _SubCat = txtSubCat.Text;
        PhtxtSubCat.Controls.Add(txtSubCat);
    }
```